# reformat mongodb via python write function

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to pull documents from MongoDB into a text file in CSV format via Python. The problem is the content from Mongo includes the header info in each record in the new file. For example:

```
u'mac': u'001dd07c7a90', u'opt80': u'dslforum.org', u'ip': u'10.242.9.30', u'hostname': u'pnrg',and etc
```

I'm looking to write to a file in a table format (i.e).

```
mac           opt80         ip          hostname
001dd07c7a90  dslforum.org  10.242.9.30 pnrg
```

I hope the table format above is reserved for those to understand.

Is there a way to write into a CSV file? Not sure how to do so. My code is below.

```
# Open a file csv format to send reformated Mongo data to it
fo = open('Merged_Data_Output.txt', 'w')

# Finding all hostname records containing 'pnrg'
opnrg = db.systemlog1.find({'hostname': 'pnrg'}).limit(5)

# Writing documents into a table format
for rcds in pnrg:
    print rcds
    fo.write(str(rcds))
    fo.write('\n')
fo.close()
```

Comment: Have you checked out python's [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the built-in csv Python module.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html